# Saving reports query to database

Tags: mysql, report, save

I am developing an web app that is reliant on reports being dynamically generated. The client has specified they would like to save reports searches to the database for future use, specifically generating reports from the last 6 month.

I can add the query to the database no bother, the problem is trying to get the date to be dynamic depending on the date the report is ran. The 3 types are bi-monthly, monthly and 6 monthly reports.

My question is:

How would I go about saving the query and getting it to calculate the current date and search based on the report type (2, 3 or 6 month). Is it a simple case of editing the sql query when I pull the query from the database, or would it be easier to split up the query into different parts to make it easier to manipulate/edit later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a second column in your table where you store the query with the dynamic column. Use that column in your dynamic query